# Do integral transforms with meromorphic kernels always have analytic continuation?

Tags: complex-analysis, integral-transforms

Do integral transforms with meromorphic kernels always have analytic continuation ?
I think so, but I do not know how to prove it.

For clarity with analytic continuation I assume it was already analytic somewhere.

Comment: By "meromorphic kernel with analytic continuation" do you mean "meromorphic kernel on all of $\mathbb{C}$"?

Comment: Yes thats what I mean.

Comment: Mick? Are you okay? I had no other way to contact you and I noticed you disappeared from the chat, I felt responsible for this - due to my joke. If this was the reason, I was only kidding, sorry if it hurt you.

Comment: @GustavoBandeira Dont worry my friend. I do not even know what you are talking about :)